# Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a program that automate some daily Excel work.

I just want to copy data from a sheet to another using pandas but I got an error. Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd

File1 = pd.read_excel('FileName1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(File1.columns)
print(File1['Date'][2])
File2 = pd.read_excel('FileName2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
File1['Date'][0] = File2['Date'][0]
```

Here's the error:

> ```
> SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
> ```

Comment: probably this will be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: I saw it before but I didn't understand at first, anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is being thrown in the statement `File1['Date'][0] = File2['Date'][0]`. Pandas does not allow assignment using indexes like typical lists. Try using indexing with [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html): `File1.loc[0, 'Date'] = File2.loc[0, 'Date']`

Comment: Would you please tell me how to save these changes?

Comment: You can use `pd.to_excel('FileName1.xlsx')`

Comment: I've got an error : module pandas has no attribute 'to_excel'